# Как узнать что использовать: render() или renderPartial() в Yii2

Tags: yii2, pjax

У меня есть сайт, написанный на yii2. в основном он использует Pjax() для отображения данных, поэтому рендирится они с помощью renderPartial(). Но иногда надо эту же страницу отобразить просто по ссылке, без Pjax(). То есть надо использовать render().

Вопрос: как понять, что и когда использовать?

Comment: насколько я знаю, `render` автоматом заменяется на `renderPartial`, опуская layout, если в теле запроса есть параметр `_pjax` и в заголовках `X-PJAX`, так-что дополнительные действия не требуются, можно везде использовать `render`. Правда каким магическим методом это делается я не нашёл. Но для пущей уверенности можете проверять сами: `if (Yii::$app->request->get('_pjax') { ... }`

Comment: в виджете pjax в общем вся "магия" и происходит https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/widgets/Pjax.php#L126

Comment: может у меня от как то не верно работает, но когда я сам проверяю - работает (спасибо @Blacknife), если оставить что бы виджет сам разбирался - нет подгрузки через Ajax, просто переход на страницу